# UI Buttons Stop Working After I Load Another Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have UI buttons to toggle sound. OnClick event is linked to this singleton GameObject. when I move to the next scene and come back to the main scene, I find OnClick object becomes missing while object is still there in the hierarchy! so what's the problem ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SoundsManagerController : MonoBehaviour {

    static SoundsManagerController Instance = null;       



    void Awake()
    {
        // First we check if there are any other instances conflicting
        if (Instance != null )
        {
            // If that is the case, we destroy other instances
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else { 
            // Here we save our singleton instance
            Instance = this;

            // Furthermore we make sure that we don't destroy between scenes (this is optional)
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void toggleSound(){

        Instance.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().enabled = !Instance.GetComponent< AudioSource> ().enabled;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate canvas for the button and keep them as child of the singleton object.

If you already have a canvas in the scene, make sure the button is set as child of the canvas whenever your are going to a scene.

When these should be fixing your issue, you should consider not using a button with the singleton object. Get the singleton object in `Start()` in any scene and access sound toggle from the already placed button which is maintaining your UI layout.

Get the singleton object at start that holding the toggle method calling function.

```
SoundManagerController soundManager;

void Start ()
{
 soundManager = GameObject.FindWithTag("audio_manager_tag").GetComponent <SoundManagerController>();
}
```

Call the below method from toggle button.

```
public void CallToggleMethod()
{
 soundManager.toggleSound ();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. but can you provide a link or example for better approach because I don't like having multiple canvas and making them child of singleton object

Comment: Where is the UI button placed for toggling?